# У меня не срабатывает в терминале библиотека laravel - mix

Tags: laravel-mix

Я пытаюсь закачать и использовать библиотеку laravel - mix но при вводе команды cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js ./ выдает, что cp не  является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Пытался вместо cp ввести copy но выдавало ошибку синтаксиса.
Я работаю на системе Windows.

Comment: для windows - команда: copy node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js ./

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй установить laravel mix заного. Сначала убедитесь что у вас работает npm. Если нет то установите. После выполните команду `npm init -y` потом `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev`. Одно замечание, команды нужно выполнять в папке вашего проекта!